# How do I update my Lubuntu software?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I have an old laptop on which I installed Lubuntu a rather long time ago. I need that pc to compile a Kivy app but I can't even install Python 3.6 since `sudo apt-get update` gives me the following output:

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Nie udało się pobrać http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu disco InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/richardgv/compton/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So as stated in the title: is there any way for my to update my system so that I can use all of it's functions?

Oh, and I would also like to add that I'm a huge noob if it comes to Linux related things :/

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 (including *flavors* like Lubuntu) *release-upgraded* to 19.10, which reaches EOL itself today, so you'll need to hurry if you want to *release-upgrade* as was tested by Lubuntu team members. Standard releases have only 9 months of supported life, so calculated when 19.04 (2019-April) reaches EOL isn't difficult.  A re-install of Lubuntu 20.04 LTS however maybe a better option (it'll definitely be faster, and you don't need to erase your user files with the correct options, but backup first of course).

Comment: The Lubuntu manual page for upgrading can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html , the release notes for the intended upgrade path can be found at https://lubuntu.me/eoan-released/ or probably more useful the current release https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/  Main 19.10/eoan release notes are https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes (which include upgrade instructions but I'd follow the Lubuntu manual)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should update your repository, open terminal and run:

`nano /etc/apt/sources.list` 
Replace the old repository with the new repository, save the file. Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: How exactly should my repositories look? Right now all my sources are `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted`. Is that correct?

Comment: What version of LUBUNTU are you running?

Comment: When I typed in `cat /etc/os-release` it returned Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Paste the result from `lsb_release -a`

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 19.04
Release: 19.04
Codename: disco

Comment: Try installing from archives
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110732/discussion-between-ruby-and-xjwg).